# Realm - React Native and Objective C

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a project that will be partly in react native mostly for the view layer and part objective-c for some heavy lifting. I would like to use Realm as a db for this and be able to access it from javascript and objective-c.

Wondering if anyone else has run into this and what approach did you take to handling it?

What I'm leaning towards is using objective-c realm and creating a RCTBridgeModule for it so I can use it from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been told, it's possible to run both Realm React Native and Realm Objective-C in the same codebase.

As long as the schema definitions in the React Native code and the Objective-C code match, you should be able to read and write to the same Realm file on disk from both the React Native and Objective-C portions of your code.

Comment: I'm trying to do this. The issue I'm having is actually linking the project -- if I use general setup instructions on JS/React side and Obj-C side, I get duplicate symbol compiler errors, presumably because both sides are discretely linking the same library.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an official plugin already exists for that: https://realm.io/docs/react-native/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yup I'm aware that there is a plugin for React Native the problem is if I use the React Native Realm plugin I cannot call into that from my objective-c codebase.

Comment: @Nick Did you ever figure this out? I'm curious how you link Realm on both sides. Seems like it should work if the store/schemas match.

Comment: @isaac yea, if you're using the same c++ core between React Native and ObjC you can get them to work. When I looked into this originally the ObjC SDK was using a slightly newer version of the c++ core which caused my initial issue, going back to a version that supported the core that the RN SDK was using made it work